# Tap gesture on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have a map view that when i single tap anywhere on the map I hide the navigation bar.

I'm currently using the UITapGestureRecognizer gesture.  How can I detect if they hit an annotation view and not hide the toolbar from this gesture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give an Tag property to the views. and when in your TapGestureRecognizer method

check the tag of the view and depending upon that you can perform your custom action

```
- (void)tapImagesLike:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    UIView *View = recognizer.view; 
    //use imageView.tag as the id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MKMapVie's delegate methods for this purpose

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

This delegate method will be invoked when a user selects an annotation. Use this *didSelectAnnotationView* as

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view

{        
    //annotation selected. do the stuff here for hiding toolbar
}
```

Set your mapview's delegate also

```
mView.delegate = self;
```